# How to keep expiring items in sync on the client/server

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

My site allows users to post items for sale. Each item has an expiration date and time, at which point I plan on marking it as expired and removed from the view. Right now, the client has a helper function that determines the time remaining, and marks it as expired once time remaining reaches 0. The issue with this is that the item still appears on the user's view until they have reloaded the page.

I have considered running a cron job to mark expired items, but was concerned this may be too costly as it would have to run very often to be an efficient method.

Is there a more efficient way to handle this? I was hoping to get each item reactively remove itself from the list once the time expires.

Comment: Only publish the ones which have not expired?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement in an app. I ended up using the [remcoder:chronos](https://atmospherejs.com/remcoder/chronos) package to make *time* reactive. This removed the need for an expiration key as well as any crown jobs. I used reactive time in my *Collection.find()* query which was returning the cursor of documents to display. At the expiration time they disappear automatically.